# Is $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \sin \left(\frac{x^3}{x^4+y^2}\right) >0 \}$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric?

Tags: general-topology

Is $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \sin \left(\frac{x^3}{x^4+y^2}\right) >0 \}$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric?

I think I have to use the theorem about if a function is continuous, its preimages are open, but I am not sure how to deal with the point $(0,0)$ since we don’t have continuity there...

Comment: Where did you get this question from? It is undefined whether $(0, 0)$ belongs to the set or not.

Comment: @RobArthan It is from an exam paper at university....

Comment: That's sad. I think the usual reading would be that $(0, 0)$ does not belong to the set (which means it will be open). I think it is poor practice on the part of your teachers not to have made it explicit that $(0, 0)$ is excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define $f(x,y) = \sin(\frac{x^3}{x^4 + y^2})$ where $f: \mathbb{R}\setminus \{(0,0)\} \to \mathbb{R}$ ,then $f$ is continuous on the domain of $f$.

I think your set  $A:= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \sin \left(\frac{x^3}{x^4+y^2}\right) >0 \}$ cannot contain $(0,0)$ because we cannot substitute $(0,0)$ in the formula. (And also, $f$ does not have a continuous extension to all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so there is no "way out" that way.)

So $A = f^{-1}[(0,\infty)]$ which is open in the domain of $f$ by continuity of $f$, and as the domain is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (singletons are closed), $A$ is also open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: But I **can** substitute $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ in the formula to give a formula whose meaning depends on one's interpretation of a formula containing $\frac{0}{0}$. The OP's teachers have set a badly-defined question.

Comment: @RobArthan the natural interpretation is one where $\frac{0}{0}$ never occurs as it cannot be sensibly defined. $f$ has a "natural domain". I agree it's imprecise, but common usage nonetheless.

Comment: I know it is common usage, but it should be deplored.